# How to retrieve information from outbound Twilio call with Python?

Tags: python, twilio, call, outbound

I am new to Twilio and am trying to figure out how to retrieve data from an outbound call I have successfully made using Python 3. I want to be able to retrieve things like what button has been pressed from the recipient.

After reading the Twilio docs for a little bit (then getting a little lost), I think I understand how Twilio works and why I am not able to retrieve data from a phone call. I think the Python program merely establishes a connection from Twilio to a phone number. The recipient can dial any number and I can use the  tag to get some info. But how do I direct that info to my Python program? The idea was to have Twilio (somehow) send info back to my Python program and then I can take action (like update a database).

I am guessing that Twilio will throw data somewhere else which then my Python program can go to to retrieve but I do not understand where to learn that skill. I have a basic foundation of Python 3 but not a whole lot on web development. Just some basic HTML5 and CSS3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You may have seen this [documentation on gathering user input via keypad in Python](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-gather-user-input-via-keypad-python) on an inbound call.

When you get an inbound call, Twilio makes the webhook request to find out what to do next and you respond with TwiML, for example, a `<Gather>` when you want to take information.

When you make an outbound call, you [initiate the call with the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call#create-a-call-resource) and then when the call connects, Twilio makes a webhook request to your URL. It is then that you can respond with TwiML to tell Twilio what to do and you can respond with a `<Gather>` at this stage too.

Let's gather input from an [outbound call as shown in this documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-make-outbound-phone-calls-python).

First, you purchase a Twilio phone number and configure it with a [Ngrok](http://ngrok.io) URL: this is a handy tool that opens up your local server to the web via a public URL. When you make an outbound call, you pass it this URL: `your-ngrok-url.ngrok.io/voice`.

```
from twilio.rest import Client
account_sid = 'your-account-sid'
auth_token = 'your-auth-token'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

call = client.calls.create(
    url='https://your-ngrok-url.ngrok.io/voice',
    to='phone-number-to-call',
    from_='your-twilio-number'
)
```

The URL in `client.calls.create` returns TwiML with instructions on what should happen when the user answers the phone call. Let's create a Flask application that contains code to run when the user answers the call.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse, Gather

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/voice", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def voice():
    # Start a TwiML response
    resp = VoiceResponse()
```

You would receive user input via keypad with the TwiML [Gather](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather) verb which is used to collect digits or transcribe speech during a phone call. The [Action attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#action) takes an absolute or relative URL as a value that Twilio makes an HTTP request to once the caller finishes entering digits (or the timeout is reached). That request includes the user's data and Twilio's standard request parameters.

If you gather digits from the caller, Twilio includes the `Digits` parameter containing the digits the caller typed in.

```
    gather = Gather(num_digits=1, action='/gather')
    gather.say('For sales, press 1. For support, press 2.')
    resp.append(gather)
```

If the recipient doesn't select an option, let's loop them back to the beginning so they can hear the directions again.

```
    resp.redirect('/voice')
    return str(resp)
```

However, if they do select an option and type a number into the keypad, Twilio will send a POST request back to the URL hosting your TwiML with the digit they typed. That is how you get user input via button press from the recipient and direct it back to your Python program: with `request.values['Digits']`. Based on that value (in the `choice` variable, you can update a database or something accordingly, as shown in the conditionals below.

```
@app.route('/gather', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def gather():
    """Processes results from the <Gather> prompt in /voice"""
    # Start TwiML response
    resp = VoiceResponse()

    # If Twilio's request to our app included already gathered digits,
    # process them
    if 'Digits' in request.values:
        # Get which digit the caller chose
        choice = request.values['Digits']

        # <Say> a different message depending on the caller's choice
        if choice == '1':
            resp.say('You selected sales. Good for you!')
            return str(resp)
        elif choice == '2':
            resp.say('You need support. We will help!')
            return str(resp)
        else:
            # If the caller didn't choose 1 or 2, apologize and ask them again
            resp.say("Sorry, I don't understand that choice.")

    # If the user didn't choose 1 or 2 (or anything), send them back to /voice
    resp.redirect('/voice')

    return str(resp)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the answer. Not going to lie, now I am going to learn Flask as I have never used it. And it seems like I should have at least a basic understanding.

Comment: Ok so I learned a little bit of flask. Basically here, I make a local webserver. But we use that ngrok link to create a way to get back to my local machine. Really, I should set this up first. Then, with the other code for creating a call, a webhook is done only when a call is answered. Twilio 'visits' my server and is served up TwiML made with the gather and voice response functions. That is pretty cool. I will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

@lizziepika - Excellently guiding - appreciate that !

I am trying to do a realtime transcribing system that uses speech-to-text and text-to-speech in a twilio conversation between a twilio number and a user.

1. I have been following a streaming process so that I receive user
   responses in my web-socket (flask-sockets) following this link
   (https://github.com/twilio/media-streams/tree/master/python/realtime-transcriptions). Here I face a problem as to when should I consider the user has
   stopped talking and pausing for twilio to respond.
2. If I use twiml `gather` with `input=speech` and get `request.values`
   as you mentioned
       in your answer, then the gap of 2 seconds need to be given for
       identifying that the user has stopped talking and waiting for twilio
       to respond. The problem with this is, only after this 2 seconds the
       system can start processing the response from the user. This is a
       much delayed response I believe.

Which is the suggested option I should choose from the above so that it gives a near normal conversation between twilio and the user.